# PySchools - Topic 1 Question 7

Tags: python, string

I was running through some practices for Python on PySchools.com and got stuck here. I'm sure it's a simple task. Anyone?

You can make use of the len(x) function to find out the number of characters in a string.

Examples

```
>>> greetings = "Hello World"
>>> len(greetings) # get the length of string
11
>>> greetings[0] # get the 1st character
'H'
```

Question here below:

```
greeting = "Hello Google!"
# number of characters stored in the variable greeting
number_of_char = len(greeting)

# repeat the greetings based on the number of character in 'greeting'
greetings =
```

http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s1-q7

Comment: So what was the question again?

Comment: Yeah, sorry.. just noticed it. It says here to "repeat the greetings based on the number of character in 'greeting'"

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by `repeat the greetings ...`. Is this what they want? `greetings = number_of_char * greeting` Or perhaps they want `greetings = number_of_char * [greeting]`? Maybe `' '.join(number_of_char * [greeting])`?

Comment: I was guessing that the question wanted me to print out "Hello World" in length of 13..?

Comment: I think it's this.. though it's weird..

# repeat the greetings based on the number of character in 'greeting'
greetings = greetings * number_of_char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply a string by an integer in order to repeat the string multiple times.

```
>>> 'abc' * 2
'abcabc'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this by multiplying num_of_char to greeting

```
greetings = number_of_char * greeting
```

Answer (score 0):

```
greetings = "Hello Google"
repeated_greetings = len(greetings) * greetings
print repeated_greetings
```

> > >
> >     'Hello GoogleHello GoogleHello GoogleHello GoogleHello GoogleHello GoogleHello GoogleHello GoogleHello GoogleHello GoogleHello GoogleHello Google'